# generate sub website in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a website written by mvc asp.net as blog.com.

This site use to create many page such as blog.com/supper_hero or blog.com/tomandjerry.

How to generate sub site by asp.net mvc with IIS like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [MVC.NET Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) for creating subsites. Then each subsite could be an area in your application. This way you only have to setup the IIS for your main site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create asp.net mvc **sub application** https://blog.com/supper_hero under asp.net mvc **main application**(https://blog.com) in IIS.

In IIS from the main application(https://blog.com) right click and their is option to add application click and give an alias name(supper_hero) and set physical path to the sub application(refer: image).

Don't forget to put modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" under system.webserver part in configuration.Now it will start recognising the child application.

If you are using only single Asp.Net MVC Application then you use **Areas in Asp.net** MVC or your can create different controllers(supper_hero and default) etc and it will point to same view. And url will be like https://blog.com/supper_hero and you need to be specifically type the https://blog.com/supper_hero in all the cases for pointing to that controller action

[image]